# Is there a foley directory where I can look up tips for making specific sounds?

Tags: foley

I'm just starting on the audio post for a film and was wondering if there was somewhere I could go and look up the different options that people have tried with success to replicate different sounds?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.epicsound.com/sfx

Comment: I found this site a long time ago and I totally forgot what it was, and all of my searching never brought me back to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That Epic Sound link is gold! Ric Vier's book The Sound Effects Bible is worth a read too. It cover a lot of technique, as well as a good few pages on suggested solutions for common effects.
http://www.ricviers.com/#!sound-effects-bible/cukm

Answer (score 1):

Came across http://www.ruyasonic.com/sfx_catalog.htm recently. Some good general sfx info there seeing as its based on radio drama mainly!
http://www.ruyasonic.com/sfx_closet.htm